# Representing integers as difference of semi-primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Can every integer, $k$ (where $4 \le k < n$), be written as the difference of two semi-primes whose prime factors are at most $n$ ?

or put another way:

Given positive integers $k\ge 4$, $n > k$ , do there exist primes $a,b,c,d$ at most $n$ such that $ab−cd=k$ ?

Comment: No. For example take $n=4$. The semi-primes whose prime factors are $\le 4$ are $4,6,9$ and $4$ is not the difference of any of them. Have I understood the question correctly? Did you have an example for the first case?

Comment: Sorry $n>4$ was supposed to be part of the question, as $n=4$ is trivially false.  I have edited the question to include this.

Comment: For example say $n=7$, we have
$$k=4 = 10 - 6$$
or
$$k=5 = 15 - 10$$
or
$$k=6 = 10 - 4$$